# Animation for recyclerview getting Error

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want use animation for `recyclerview` but when use animation for `recyclerview` is force close my app and display error for Context even i can not use toast in adapter how to can use animation in adapter and resolve context problem,i put my code ,how to can resolve my problem or adapter?please help me

**My Adapter**

```
public class adapter_zakeran_any extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter_zakeran_any.ItemViewHolder> {

private Context contex;
private ArrayList<Item_zakerin_any> itemlist;
Item_zakerin_any item;
int pos;
String nameeee;
int DownloadComplete;
//  String file;
public Product product;
String mylink, myname, mynamelist, namemadahi_h, namemadah_h;
public SqliteDatabase mDatabase;
private long Music_DownloadId;
private DownloadManager downloadManager;
String namee;
String file;
View view;


//  private EditText linkFileEdt;
private Intent playerService;
public static TextView namemadahi, onvanmadahi;


public static ImageView download, albumart;

String speaker_name, masir, link, imagee;
MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriver;
byte[] art;
String flink, shname, shonvane;
SharedPreferences preferences;


int lastPosition = -1;


public adapter_zakeran_any(Context contex, ArrayList<Item_zakerin_any> itemlist) {
    this.contex = contex;
    this.itemlist = itemlist;
}

@Override
public adapter_zakeran_any.ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    view = inflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.cardview_zakeran_any, parent, false);
    adapter_zakeran_any.ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = new adapter_zakeran_any.ItemViewHolder(view);
    return itemViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(adapter_zakeran_any.ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {

    item = itemlist.get(position);
    nameeee = item.getInfo();


    holder.namemadahi.setText(item.getInfo());
    holder.madah.setText(item.getSpeaker_name());
    holder.link.setText(item.getFile());
    final String ml = (String) holder.link.getText();


    namemadahi_h = (String) holder.namemadahi.getText();
    namemadah_h = item.getSpeaker_name();


    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(contex, R.anim.item_animation_fall_down);
    holder.itemView.startAnimation(animation);
    lastPosition = position;


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (itemlist != null) {
        return itemlist.size();

    }

    return 0;
}


public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    public CardView cvItem;
    public TextView namemadahi;
    public TextView madah;
    public TextView link;
    public ImageView download_any_rv;


    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cvItem = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        namemadahi = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.namemadahi);
        madah = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.madah);


        link = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.link);
        download_any_rv = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.download_anyrv);


    }
}
```

**my error**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     java.lang.NullPointerException
>                         at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:71)
>                         at com.example.kaveh.zakerinekordestan.adapter_zakeran_any.onBindViewHolder(adapter_zakeran_any.java:103)
>                         at com.example.kaveh.zakerinekordestan.adapter_zakeran_any.onBindViewHolder(adapter_zakeran_any.java:34)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6354)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6387)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5343)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5606)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5448)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5444)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3600)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3329)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3867)
>                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>                         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
>                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>                         at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:131)
>                         at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
>                         at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1391)
>                         at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:870)
>                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:452)
>                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:452)
>                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:452)
>                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1986)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1740)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1009)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5508)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer$Callba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting error because when last items comes its getting null value.

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>                     at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:71)

Try out this : Create a method on your Adapter class and call from OnBindViewHolder method

```
setAnimation(holder.itemView, position);
```

initialize globally

```
 // Allows to remember the last item shown on screen
    private int lastPosition = -1;
```

Here is full Code :

```
        @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(adapter_zakeran_any.ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {

        item = itemlist.get(position);
        nameeee = item.getInfo();


        holder.namemadahi.setText(item.getInfo());
        holder.madah.setText(item.getSpeaker_name());
        holder.link.setText(item.getFile());
        final String ml = (String) holder.link.getText();


        namemadahi_h = (String) holder.namemadahi.getText();
        namemadah_h = item.getSpeaker_name();

     // Here you apply the animation when the view is bound
        setAnimation(holder.itemView, position);

    }

 /**
     * Here is the key method to apply the animation
     */
    private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position)
    {
        // If the bound view wasn't previously displayed on screen, it's animated
        if (position > lastPosition)
        {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.item_animation_fall_down);
            viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
            lastPosition = position;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you,im change this line and worked:) Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(viewToAnimate.getContext(), R.anim.item_animation_fall_down);

Comment: Welcome @jad,Happy coding.